# useCapture in listener of addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I want to determine the boolean value of useCapture inside the listener method of target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]). Is there a way to do that or is it possible?

```
target.addEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture]);
divs[i].addEventListener("click", listener, false);

function listener()
{
    //Determine the false of useCapture here;
}
```

Comment: where is useCapture data stored? is it a value/attribute on the clicked item?

Comment: @CrimsonChin: That's a description of the third argument that `addEventListener` accepts.

Comment: @amnotiam sorry, I should of read the question properly

Comment: I have the same question...

Answer (score 0):

There are three [event phases](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-phase):

> - The **capture phase**: the event object must propagate through the target's ancestors from the [defaultView](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-defaultView) to the target's parent.
>     This phase is also known as the *capturing phase*. Event listeners
>     registered for this phase must handle the event before it reaches its
>     target.
> - The **target phase**: the event object must arrive at the event object's [event target](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-event-target). This phase is also known as the
>     *at-target* phase. Event listeners registered for this phase must handle the event once it has reached its target. If the [event
>     type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-event-type) indicates that the event must not bubble, the event object
>     must halt after completion of this phase.
> - The **bubble phase**: the event object propagates through the target's ancestors in reverse order, starting with the target's parent
>     and ending with the [defaultView](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120906/#glossary-defaultView). This phase is also known as the
>     *bubbling phase*. Event listeners registered for this phase must handle the event after it has reached its target.

You can know the current phase through the `eventPhase` property of the `event`.

However, the problem is that there isn't a perfect correspondence:

- If `event.eventPhase` is `1` (capturing phase), it means `useCapture` was `true`.
- If `event.eventPhase` is `3` (bubbling phase), it means `useCapture` was `false`.
- If `event.eventPhase` is `2` (at target), `useCapture` could have been either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score -1):

If the listener is not passed with a different value for `useCaputre`, you can check if the listener is in the capture phase.

```
var useCapture = event.eventPhase === Event.CAPTURING_PHASE;
```